# C# and property change notifications

Tags: c#

Why does C# make me do this:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler Changed;
    public void OnChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Changed != null)
            Changed(sender, e);
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    private string _name;
    public string Name { 
        get { return _name; } 
        set 
        { 
            _name = value; 
            OnChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name")); 
        }
    }
}
```

intead of something like this:

```
[GeneratesChangeNotifications]
public class SomeClass {
    [GeneratesChangeNotification] 
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I know you can do this with PostSharp and other 3rd party libraries... but something so integral and otherwise error prone (e.g. misspelling the name in the string), I think, should be built into the language... why doesn't Microsoft do this?... is there some purist language reason why this doesn't happen. It's a common enough need.

Comment: Another [*why doesn't C# implement feature X?*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/22/why-doesn-t-c-implement-top-level-methods.aspx) -  The answer is always the same: because no one ever designed, specified, implemented, tested, documented and shipped that feature.   Features are not cheap, and Microsoft tries very hard to make sure that shipped features give the best possible benefits to users given constrained time, effort and money budgets.

Comment: I suggest reading [csharp.2000things.com blogs tagged INotifyPropertyChanged](http://csharp.2000things.com/tag/inotifypropertychanged/).

Comment: That's a great answer... I was completely unaware of CallerMemberName. Thanks! It still sucks having to have two properties and a function call to implement this functionality. But... at least I don't have to worry about my spelling! I wonder if there is a microsoft suggestion box somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far here is the best that I've come up with... I've written a class called NotifyPropertyChanged... it handles the property name, the test for if it's changed or not, the update of the local variable, and the notification of the change... and the SetProperty function is generic, so one function will work with all types of properties... works pretty well.

(Also notice you can call OnPropertyChanged with several property names if you like.)

```
public class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(params string[] props)
    {
        foreach (var prop in props)
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }

    public bool SetProperty<T>(ref T oldValue, T newValue, [CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
    {
        if (oldValue == null && newValue == null)
            return false;
        if (oldValue != null && oldValue.Equals(newValue))
            return false;
        oldValue = newValue;
        OnPropertyChanged(prop);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
public class MyClass : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Text { get => _text; set => SetProperty(ref _text, value); }
    string _text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My `RaisePropertyChanged` always uses the caller member name, or if needed reflects the property name passed in in an expression (ie, if I need to make one property notify for another). You cannot always guarantee that all properties can notify, and being able to notify more than one at a time is therefore useful.

In addition, with the standard model, using an event allows anyone to subscribe, which an attributed model can not.

Comment: In my suggested solution... the class attribute would effectively generate the Changed event property and the OnChanged method... and I know that attributes don't yet have this ability. (Note: They do in PostSharp)

Comment: An attribute adds metadata. As far as I can tell, there's no way to make intellisense or the compiler allow you to access a property that doesn't exist on a class until compile time.

Comment: I think PostSharp uses a preprocessor to generate the code, but you're right about intellisense... but I'm sure Microsoft could make C# handle this gracefully if they wanted to.